# How do I get the alias string of a class in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var alias:String = 'models.User';
registerClassAlias(alias, models.User);

// If I have the alias, then
// I can get the class like this:
var klass:Class = flash.net.getClassByAlias(alias);

// How do I do the reverse
// (get the alias from the class)?
//
// I want to do this, but I can't find a 
// 'getAliasByClass' function.
alias = getAliasByClass(klass);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [flash.utils.describeType()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#describeType())

Comment: What would you parse in the describeType() XML to get the [RemoteClass(alias="com.foo.javaClassName")]

From this code example it looks like you can get attributes using @.

                override protected function encodeComplex(o:Object, b:IBinary, context:IContext=null):void
                {                        
                       var desc:XML = describeType(o);
                       var classAlias:String = desc.@alias;
//...
}

Answer (score 1):

[getQualifiedClassName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName()) should do the trick.

```
alias = flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName( klass );
// should return: "models::User"
```

You can pass it a class reference, or an instance of the class, either way.

Comment: I need the class alias, not the actual AS3 class name.

Comment: Oh - you mean essentially that you want to query which, if any, alias has been registered to a given class? I don't think you can do that. Even if you could, there could be multiple aliases for a given class, couldn't there? I don't know this definitively though, so I'll leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above you can call [flash.utils.describeType()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()) and use "reflection" on your Actionscript object's class to query attributes, properties, methods of the object.

For example the following code snippet for [ObjectCodec.as](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=7&ct=rc#a2tKkY7STZE/trunk/ygg/encoding/amf/type/v3/ObjectCodec.as&q=lang:actionscript%20describeType&exact_package=http://yggsaw.googlecode.com/svn) seems to retrieve the alias attribute by using "@":

```
override protected function encodeComplex(o:Object, b:IBinary, context:IContext=null):void
{
        var desc:XML = describeType(o);
        var classAlias:String = desc.@alias;
        //...
}
```